# Upgrading from raring to saucy broke many of my fonts in certain applications

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, fonts

I upgraded from raring to saucy over the weekend.  Two of my applications, dzen2 and xmobar, won't display the fonts they used to.  I'd mostly been using fixed and 6x12.

xmobar doesn't run with these fonts.  dzen2 shows some generic font I can't identify.  I can change the size but not the font.

The only exception is terminus.  I looped over xlsfonts and piped them into a dzen2 to see what still worked.  Variants of terminus were fine.  Everything else used the same generic looking font face.  No idea why.

I haven't found any other applications with font issues since the update, but I haven't tried too hard to look either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna answer my own here.  The arch wiki pointed me to

http://iamfuss.deviantart.com/journal/How-to-install-artwiz-pixel-fonts-in-Ubuntu-226000883

Looks like the culprit was /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf which blocked bitmap fonts from being added to the font cache.  I have no idea why I had them before, but things are working for me now.